# Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Domain\userid'

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, windows-authentication, impersonation

I have website hosted in IIS with application pool identity set to 'Local systems'.
Windows authentication - Enabled
ASP .net Impersonation - Enabled
all other are disabled
ASP.net impersonation identity set to Authenticated user.

I am getting error:

> Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'PRD\12345'.

```
<add name="testConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=testserver;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is my connection string

Comment: That would depend on your connection string.

Comment: <add name="testConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=testserver;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

This is my connection string.
What change I will need to do?

Comment: You will likely need to add your application pool as a user on the DB

Comment: You might get some basic ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0

Comment: Could you connect your database by setting application pool identity to local system? If it fix the problem. Then you need to change application pool identity back and grant permission in your sql database. The name of application pool is "IIS Apppool\<poolname>".

Answer (score 0):

Have you also created a User in the database mapped to the login? If the login has not been at a minimum granted the CONNECT DATABASE permissions then it will not be able to connect when a specific database is included in the connection string

Comment: No I haven't created user in database becacuse I set Impersonation to authenticated user in IIS.
For which user we should grant permissions in SQL server if we set IIS impersonation identity to Authenticted user?

Comment: SQL Server has two levels of identities - the login, which is defined in the master database and for each database that this login needs to have access to you also need to have a database user mapped to the login.  Permissions within the database are assigned to the database user.   If for example your login is PRD\12345 then you would initially create the login using `USE [master]; CREATE LOGIN [PRD\12345] FROM WINDOWS`.  You would then change to your database and run the following `USE [test]; CREATE USER [12345] FOR LOGIN [PRD\12345]; GRANT CONNECT DATABASE TO [12345];`